# Issue with mail gun send API using HTML in email body

Tags: python, mailgun

hi I have a python code which sends email using the Mail Gun API.

import requests

```
def send_simple_message(email_body, email_id):
    response = requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/xxxx.mailgun.org/messages",
        auth=("api", "xxxx-xxxx-xxx"),
        data={"from": "Excited User <mailgun@xxxxx.mailgun.org>",
            "to": email_id,
            "subject": "Please confirm your subscription to Mailing-List XYZ",
            "text":"Subscription message",
            "html": email_body})
    print("Send email API post")
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.text
    else:
        return "Error from API post {0}".format(response.status_code)
```

Here is my email_body

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Please confirm your subscription to Mailing-List XYZ?</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "http://schema.org",
      "@type": "EmailMessage",
      "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "ConfirmAction",
        "name": "Confirm Subscription",
        "handler": {
          "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
          "url": "{{ confirm_url }}",
          "method": "http://schema.org/HttpRequestMethod/POST",
        }
      },
      "description": "Confirm subscription to mailing list XYZ"
    }
    </script>
    <p>
      Dear John, please confirm that you wish to be subscribed to the mailing list XYZ.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason I keep getting Error from API post 400.

Comment: first you should check `response.text` - maybe there are useful information about problem.

Comment: Got it thanks. To email Id was invalid.